# Python 3.6 "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, python-3.x, index-error

Can someone tell me my mistake?

```
realpair = input("")
realpairfinal = []
rp = list(realpair)
print(rp[0],rp[1])
for i in range(0, len(realpair)):
    a = []
    v1 = rp[0]
    v2 = rp[1]
    rp.pop(0)
    rp.pop(0)
    a.append(v1)
    a.append(v2)
    realpairfinal.append(a)
pair = realpairfinal
pair2 = realpairfinal
print(realpairfinal)
```

if my input is 123456, realpairfinal is supposed to be [[1, 2][3, 4][5, 6]] but it tells me:

```
1 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
    v1 = rp[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

```
realpair = input("")
realpairfinal = []
rp = list(realpair)
for i in range(0, len(realpair)-3):
    a = []
    v1 = rp[0]
    v2 = rp[1]
    rp.pop(0)
    rp.pop(0)
    a.append(v1)
    a.append(v2)
    realpairfinal.append(a)
pair = realpairfinal
pair2 = realpairfinal
print(realpairfinal)
```

Subtract three from the length. Output: `[['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]`

Comment: Yes thanks that was right, but instead of subtracting, I just did `for i in range(0, len(realpair), 2)` that seemed to be a more universal way to write it down, so the system can get more or less input too

Answer (score 0):

```
pairs = [list(realpair[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(realpair), 2)]
```

This is using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to construct a list instead of making an empty list and then appending elements to it.

I'm taking substring of length 2, making it into a list of characters using list() which is then added to the outer list (using list comprehension)

Comment: what is that supposed to mean, I have never seen a code like this in python. could you explain it please? But I thank you for the _2_ at the end of the range.. that was my mistake

Comment: There you go. ^^